# Node's net.connect() in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, browserify

I was wondering if it's possible to use this node.js TCP abstraction in the browser? I'm looking into Browserify right now but maybe something already exists, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

you can proxy tcp connections using socket.io and [tcp.js](https://github.com/bgaff/tcp.js)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use plain TCP in browsers yet (it is a chrome experiment), you should use some module like [Socket.io](http://socket.io/), it is like TCP, has events like `socket.on("message")` like the TCP.